# Дано двузначное число - N. Найти: а) число десятков в нем;б) число единиц в нем; Подскажите пж в чём не прав

Tags: java

```
package s02;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int n = requestNumber();
      int m = n / 10; //кол-во десятков
      int c = n / 1; //количество единиц??

        System.out.println(m);
        System.out.println(c);

               }
```

Comment: Формально говоря, число единиц совпадает с целой частью числа (для положительных), однако по всей видимости ваш преподаватель имел в виду остаток от деления на `10`. То есть `c=n%10`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости имеется ввиду остаток от деления на 10, т.е.

```
 с = n % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое число с конца это число единиц, а второе с конца это десятки. Соответственно, если с целого числа вычесть десятки, то останутся единицы, это и будет число единиц!

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = n / 10; //кол-во десятков
        int c = n - m * 10; //количество единиц

        System.out.println("Количество десятков: " + m);
        System.out.println("Количество единиц: " + c);
```

или

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = n / 10; //кол-во десятков
        int c = n % 10; //количество единиц

        System.out.println("Количество десятков: " + m);
        System.out.println("Количество единиц: " + c);
```